# How to call a function inside a nested if loop (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, function, oauth-2.0

I am working with oAuth2.0 package. Here a function "**saveToken**" *generates and saves an access token every time user sends a post request with allowed credentials*. But this function generates new access token and stores it each time user requests a token. I want to add a **condition** to check if the existing token is expired or not. if not then generate a new access token and save it. But I'm not understanding how this needs to be done.

Below function is modified and currently I am checking if there is a token for the user in DB. How can I make the token generation a function and call it inside the nested if?

***I would be glad if someone helps me with this one.***

```
var saveToken = function (token, client, user, callback) {
    token.client = {
      id: client.clientId,
    };
  
    token.user = {
      username: user.username,
    };
    var tokenInstance = new tokenModel(token);
    tokenModel
      .findOne({
        user: { username: token.user.username },
      })
      .lean()
      .exec(
        function (callback, err, token) {
          if (!token) {
            tokenInstance.save(
              function (callback, err, token) {
                token = token.toObject();
                delete token._id;
                delete token.__v;
  
                callback(err, token);
              }.bind(null, callback)
            );
            console.log("No token found!!! NEW TOKEN GERENATED");
          } else {
            let currentDate = new Date().getTime()
            let tokenExpires = new Date(token.accessTokenExpiresAt).getTime();
            let expiry = tokenExpires - currentDate
            console.log("currentDate: ", currentDate);
            console.log("tokenExpires: ", tokenExpires);
            if (expiry < 0) {
                console.log("token expired");
          // ****** HERE I WANT TO REGENERATE ANOTHER TOKEN AND SAVE TO DB *******
            }
                else if(expiry > 0){
                    console.log("token Still alive");
                }
            }
          callback(err, token);
        }.bind(null, callback)
      );
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I properly understand your use-case and question, but in `else` block you already have existing token and still can use `TokenModel` inside.

What you can do is to remove existing token by ID and after that create a new one with `TokenInstance` properties you constructed at the beginning. Example:

```js
if (expiry < 0) {
  console.log("token expired");
  TokenModel.deleteOne({id: token.id}).exec() // handle deletion
  TokenInstance.save() // save new one here
}
```

Please keep in mind that it's pseudo-code and you should adjust it to your needs which means probably doing `TokenInstance.save` in `deleteOne` exec when it's succesfull, but you should be able to handle that.

Is that answer enough? Or maybe did I understand your question in a wrong way?

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not getting the TokenInstance.save() will generate new one. I was calling the whole function here. You've cleared my confusion.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!